# Why are test marked as passed in spite of failures

Tags: scala, scalatest, scalacheck

I'm using Scalatest/Scalacheck with custom generators. I observe that tests are marked as success even if some tests failed. In below example test "*should add processing timestamp*" was *Falsified*. Yet sbt test passed.

```
+ OK, passed 100 tests.
[info] - should add product info to event 
[info] - should not alter rest of event
+ OK, passed 100 tests.
! Falsified after 0 passed tests.
> ARG_0: List("([B@27d10fe1,...)")
> ARG_0_ORIGINAL: List("([B@3c8057ce,...)")
[info] - should add processing timestamp
[info] ScalaTest
[info] Run completed in 4 seconds, 792 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 3
[info] Suites: completed 1, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 3, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] All tests passed.
[info] Passed: Total 3, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 3
[success] Total time: 8 s, completed Sep 11, 2017 6:54:28 PM
```

Why is test not failing??

***UPDATE:***
sbt 0.13, scalatest 3.0.1, scalacheck 1.13.4 and the test case is

```
  it should "add processing timestamp" in {
    Prop.forAll(sizedGen(TestInputGen.Generate)) { in => 
      val out = processor.input(in)

      out.forall(o => {
        val outTS = o._2.get("timestamps")
        (outTS.getModule() == "PrimaryProcessor")
      })
    }
  }.check
```

Comment: The test is failing. The task is succeding.

Comment: """[info] Tests: succeeded 3, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0""" ---
Failed test is 0.

Comment: Ok. Can you provide the test that is failing but passing? The command you used to run (sbt test i assume) and the versions of sbt and scalatest.

Comment: I've updated the post with the info you asked. Yes, I run sbt test or testOnly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use scalacheck prop generators in scalatest FlatSpec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29059484/how-to-use-scalacheck-prop-generators-in-scalatest-flatspec)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using ScalaTest style of property based testing as opposed to the ScalaCheck style of property testing, your properties need to return a `Matcher` or an `Assertion` instead of a `Boolean` expression.

From the [documentation](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/writing_scalacheck_style_properties#selectingAStyle):

> In the ScalaTest property style you use the word whenever instead of ==> and either an assertion or matcher expression instead of a boolean expression

Below in an example you can use to test this. The test tests that the length of 2 concatenated strings is always bigger than the length of any of the strings used in the concatenation. This should fail when both strings are empty

#### Compiles but tests pass because we are using a Boolean expression

```
import org.scalatest.prop.PropertyChecks
import org.scalatest.{FlatSpec, Matchers}

final class StringSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers with PropertyChecks {

  behavior of "String"

  it should "concatenate" in {
    forAll { (a: String, b: String) =>
      (a + b).length > a.length && (a + b).length > b.length
    }
  }
}
```

#### Compiles and fails as expected because it uses `Matchers

```
import org.scalatest.prop.PropertyChecks
import org.scalatest.{Assertion, FlatSpec, Matchers}

final class StringSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers with PropertyChecks {

  behavior of "String"

  it should "concatenate" in {
    forAll { (a: String, b: String) =>
      (a + b).length should be > a.length
      (a + b).length should be >= b.length
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. While this is in the right direction, I found that a more accurate answer was already given in another SO question. I've marked this as a duplicate of the other SO question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29059484/how-to-use-scalacheck-prop-generators-in-scalatest-flatspec